# Why do induction motors still use a lot of power with no load?

Tags: induction-motor

I have a small-ish (2.2KW) single phase 230v induction motor on a compressor, and out of interest started it with no load and measured the power draw.

It was using around 400w steady with no load at all (bare spindle)
I would have expected it to only use enough power to maintain its speed (a few watts)

Why is this?

...I'm assuming its not faulty

Comment: What did you use to measure the power draw?

Comment: I am assuming the way you measure things is faulty. You might have measured VA. Though I would say that ~10% is a good ballpark for an idle consumption, so you are not that far off

Comment: I have a plug-in power meter that has always been very accurate,  it shows aprox 2200w on FULL load

Comment: Does your plug-in power meter have a name?

Comment: Why the -1?? it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft: "that as always  been very accurate" how did you test? It might coincidentally show things fine for the pf at full load, but who knows what the pf is at idle load?

Comment: It might be a good idea to measure the no-load current. It also might be a good idea to see if the complete motor data can be found online. Even the full nameplate data might give a hint of whether or not there is a problem.

Comment: I've had the meter for years, I say its been accurate simply because it has always displayed expected results, for example a set of 6x 400w flood lights read a draw of 2400w aprox. Its an in-line one that you plug into the wall, then the appliance into that.
Unfortunately this motor has no plate as it fell off years ago, I think its a Marelli Motori, definately 3HP/2.2KW.

Comment: @digitallightcraft: I have a similar power meter that would show the 2400w of the floodlights just fine, but would be 50% off on your motor and over 200% off on my led desklight

Answer (score 2):

At no load, induction motor iron, friction and windage losses are nearly the same as at full load. Stator copper loss does not drop to zero because the magnetizing current can be a third of full-load current. The rotor resistive losses will be quite low. For a three-phase motor, 400 watts seems quite high, but might not be unreasonable for a single-phase motor.

Comment: Thats interesting - So it could potentially be very counter-intuitive to run an over-size motor for low-load applications...

Comment: My intuition has always told me that an oversized motor is likely to be less efficient than a closely sized motor. However I have been surprised to see motor data showing peak efficiency at considerably below rated load.

Comment: Typically a single phase motor in that power class will have an efficiency of 60 to 70% maximum, and it will need extra power over a three phase machine since it most likely has a run capacitor and winding always swallowing up current.

Answer (score 2):

floodlights are a resistive load which means the power factor is 1 which means that current and voltage follow each other closely.

A lesser powerfactor (as you'll see with a inductive load) will have the current and voltage being out of sync.

Cheap power meters will measure current and voltage separately and then multiply them. This can lead to high power readings even when the actual power is less.

Comment: Interesting, thanks - I think mine measures power factor, but will check.